# Can We Play Pathfinder Society Adventure Card Guild Seasons With Normal Characters?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

Suppose that I have a box of Pathfinder Adventure Card Game: Mummy's Mask with adventure packs 1-6.  I've already played through Mummy's Mask but I'd like to play more Pathfinder Adventure Card Game.

I've noticed that "Pathfinder Society Adventure Card Guild" has what looks like an alternate adventure path, [Season of Factions' Favor](http://paizo.com/store/pathfinder/pathfinderSociety/pfsacg/season4).  There seems to be a lot of alternate rules around this -- everyone has to buy a class deck and get upgrades from their class deck instead of the box.  I don't need these rules, because I just want to play the game with my friends, and I'm happy to get upgrades directly from the box.  (Also, I'd rather avoid spending $80 on class decks if that's not necessary.)

If I play through Season of Factions' Favor using standard Mummy's Mask characters (not Class Decks), will everything work properly?  Will it be easier or harder than using Class Decks?  Is there anything I should watch out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My playgroup did this for both Skulls and Shackles and Wrath of the Righteous. We enjoyed it.

Technically, yes, the playthrough is slightly easier if you are ignoring the class deck restrictions (which are not very fun). You can't count it as an organized play game, however.

One recommendation if you want to maintain some of the challenge of the character deck version: Restrict players to changing one card per scenario from their decks. This is the biggest part of the difficulty in using the character decks.

[The other part is that the character decks are not very well constructed to support all their characters. One glaring example is the warrior who can use 1 spell in her deck. So the warrior character deck has spells in it (which is useless for the other warriors), but only a few (which means very little selection for her). One recommended change for a home game that does want to use the character decks is to allow characters to dip into a second deck that fits their character's theme. Another would be to just allow a player to use all the decks they have.]